# Text search and replace

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to search and replace the value in `file2.txt` with value from `file1.txt` as below:

`file1.txt`:

```
A value1
B value2
C value3
D value4
E value5
F value6
```

`file2.txt`:

```
A
value6
E
B
value3
```

Wanted `output.txt`:

```
value1
value6
value5
value2
value3
```

Comment: How large are the files? Is there ever a case where something in the first column of file1 comes elsewhere in the second column of file1?

Comment: please do [edit] and clarify your question then with exact format your input files are and what you have tried so far to achieve what expected output

Answer (score 1):

This key pair replacement thing is best done as a script, IMHO, unless you want a command-line stream solution as a challenge. A script will allow for future generalization.  E.g. in Python it would look as follows:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                              
map = {}
with open('file1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        t = line.split()
        map[t[0]] = t[1]
with open('file2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        t = line.split()
        if t[0] in map: print(map[t[0]])
        else: print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Some suggested improvements: https://gist.github.com/davidfoerster/54be942d06cd3b93d4175e153cc55365